# Adding Dependency - Parse Error

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

After creating a new project:

```
$cd myproject
$stack new workbench
$cd workbench/
$stack setup
```

I attempted to add this ZeroMQ library by updating my `workbench.cabal`:

```
$cat workbench.cabal 
name:                workbench

...

library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5    # my note: line 19
                       zeromq4-haskell
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

But, I get the following when running `stack clean`:

```
$stack clean
Unable to parse cabal file .../workbench/workbench.cabal: NoParse "build-depends" 19
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding a comma between dependencies, e.g. `base >= 4.7 && < 5, zeromq-haskell` - even if they are on different lines.

Comment: @ErikR That's not a comment, that's an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any list in a cabal file must be comma separated, not whitespace separated. The rules concerning `.cabal` files [are listed in the user guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#package-descriptions)*:

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5,
                       zeromq4-haskell
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

<sub>* Funny enough, the definition of a `x list` is missing there.</sub>

Comment: Some fields like `exposed-modules` and `extra-source-files` _can_ at least be whitespace-separated. I'm not sure whether there are any fields that _must_ be whitespace-separated though…

Comment: ^ The complicated syntax rules of cabal files are one reason why I use `hpack` for new projects. With `hpack` I can define the project's metadata in `yaml` syntax instead.